# how to find out exact path of file using python?

Tags: python

how to find exact path of file in python.? This is very basic. But i am new to python

if my filename is file.txt

```
 path = "D:\\Utilities\\folder\\python\\model\\file.txt
```

how to get the exact path by giving only the filename?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `os.path` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), specifically `abspath(path)`, which:

> return[s] a normalized absolutized version of the pathname `path`.

Comment: if i use os.path.abspath("file.txt")  I got only D:\\file.txt. not full path

Comment: At that point you're passing a string to abspath and it's building the path based on your current working directory (presumably `D:\\`).  You need to either run the code in the same directory as `file.txt` or be more specific in your relative path.