# Python: Get path of file found in folders

Tags: python, file, path

i have written a script which is searching automatically for a file.exe file in my root directory (like C:/root/).
I have a lot of subfolders in the root directory and also a lot of file.exe files there. 
My scipt is able to detect all file.exe files but how can i get the full path of every file.exe found in the subfolders ?
Is there any function which can return me the path so i can store it into a list ?

thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python and here is what you're looking for : https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath

Comment: can you share you code, so we can see and guide you with you current code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `os` module for this:- [os.path.abspath(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath)