# Get the paths of file in python

Tags: file, python-3.x, os.path

I have a file named 'my_file.txt'. How can I get the exact paths of the file existence in Python?

Expected output as a list, `['C:/sample_folder/my_file.txt', 'C:/another_folder/test_folder/my_file.txt']`

Comment: Are you trying to search your whole hard drive?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the file already? Or are you searching the current directory you're in?

Comment: @JoshLee : Yes. Mainly from C:\ drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an absolute file path in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    for name in files:
        if name == 'README.md':
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            print(path)
```

There's also [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob):

```
import glob
for path in glob.iglob('/**/README.md', recursive=True):
    print(path)
```

And there's also [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob), an object-oriented interface to many existing functions:

```
from pathlib import Path
for path in Path('C:/').glob('**/*.txt'):
    print(path)
```