# Text file creation on device Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My Kivy app outputs a txt file on my computer but when I download it using bulldozer to my android device it doesn't create a text file at all or I can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: What's in the text file?

Comment: Log [absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51523/1113207) of file on device to see where it saved.