# Passing a DOS/Windows path in python

Tags: python-3.x

I run this code:

```
source_path="c:\temp\\"
dest_path="c:\\temp2\\"
for Name in UserNames:
run_win_cmd("robocopy "+ source_path + Name + "* "+ dest_path)
```

Name in UserNames gives a name like JBlackstone, and I get the following:

```
b'ERROR : Invalid Parameter #2 : "emp\\Flastone*"\r\n'
```

Complete with the b'. No matter how I seem to format the backslashes for the command line, it ends up wrong. Here it read `\temp` as tab emp. If I double backslashes `\\temp\\` to  the \, it puts in double backslashes. If I don't it reads them as formatting chararcters. I am using `run_win_cmd` to call the code.

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python

Comment: @Shihe Zhang Thank you for your response. That absoulutely was part of the problem.  Also I found the following (go to the very bottom of the page, its long) and the process of escaping backslashes in Windows commands is clearly explained.   [1]:(https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: You could answer your own question, or(and) mark it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I just rewrote it using Popen directly which appears to be the way most people do this in python now. I also pipe d stdout and  stderr to a file. The process of doing that formatted the text correctly.