# Opening local saved files with pandas

Tags: pandas

i'm doing my first experiments with pandas and I can't succeed in opening a locally stored file.

the path of the file is the following:

```
:\Users\MATTEO\Desktop
```

and the name of the file is yelp.csv

I'm trying the following code (Python 3)

```
import pandas as pd


yelp_raw_data = pd.read_csv(":\Users\MATTEO\Desktop\yelp.csv")
```

Comment: What is the error you receive? Are you using Windows? Also are you sure the path isn't `'C:\...'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if yelp.csv is in the same directory as your .py file,

```
yelp_raw_data = pd.read_csv("yelp.csv")
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever having trouble with the file path, you can use the absolute path:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

yelp_raw_data = pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath("MATTEO\Desktop\yelp.csv"))
```

[How to get the absolute file path in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)