# How to get the path of the file calling a function of an imported file from within the imported file

Tags: python, csv, package

I'm trying to make parsing CSVs a little easier on me later down the road so I've created a small file to allow me to run `parse_csv.toList('data.csv')` and return a list to my script. Here is what the **parse_csv.py** imported file looks like:

### parse_csv.py

```
import csv


def toList(file_location_name):
    result_list = []
    with open(file_location_name) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            result_list.append(row)
    return result_list
```

This is how I'm calling it in my scripts that are trying to utilize that file:

### import-test.py

```
import parse_csv


print(
    parse_csv.toList('../data.csv')
)
```

I'm getting the following error when I run **import-test.py**:

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{system path placeholder}\directory-test\import-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    parse_csv.toList('../data.csv')
  File "{system path placeholder}\parse_csv.py", line 6, in toList
    with open(file_location_name) as csv_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data.csv'
```

My current project directory structure looks like this

```
Project
|
|--parse_csv.py
|--data.csv
|--directory-test
   |
   |--import-test.py
```

My first thought is that when I call `open`, `'../data.csv'` is being relatively referenced according to the **parse_csv.py** file instead of the intended **import-test.py** file.

I just want to make it so **parse_csv.py** can be imported anywhere and it will respect relative file paths in the calling file.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear. I know my wording may be confusing here.

Edit for clarity: The goal is to only call `parse_csv.toList()` and have it accept a string of a relative path to the file that called it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your parse_csv.toList function accept a file object instead of a file path. This way you open a file, give that to the module and it will work. Something like:

```
import parse_csv

with open('../data.csv') as csvFile:
    print(parse_csv.toList(csvFile))
```

Or you can convert the relative path to absolute path before call toList. Refer [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python). It'll just add one extra line.

Answer (score 0):

In `import-test.py`,

```
import os.path
import parse_csv

# to retrieve import-test.py's own absolute path
abs_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)

# its dir_path
dir_path = os.path.dirname(abs_path)

# data.csv's path
csv_path = os.path.join(dir_path, '..', 'data.csv')

# use the path
print(
    parse_csv.toList(csv_path)
)
```