# Remove ../ or ./ from file path

Tags: python, path, directory-structure

I have a path to a file and a path to a directory. The file is supposed to be somewhere (multiple levels) in that directory. I want to compare the beginning of the path to the file with the path to the directory. So what I basically do is:

```
if file_path.startswith(directory_path):
    do_something()
```

Both paths are strings. Unfortunately, my path to the file includes ".." and ".". So it looks something like this: `/home/user/documents/folder/../pictures/house.jpg`. As the other path does not contain those dots, the comparison fails, obviously. Is there a way in python to remove those spots from the string? I thought of using path.join() from the os module, which did not work.
Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Comment: In my view this shouldn't have been closed. Anyways try [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath). E.g. `os.path.normpath('./test') = 'test')`. (Thx @Green-Cloak-Guy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way in python to remove those spots from the string? I thought of using path.join() from the os module, which did not work. Thanks a lot for any help :)

`os.path.abspath` will normalise the path and absolutify it. Alternatively, `pathlib.Path.resolve()`.

Comment: [Or, if absolutification is not required, `os.path.normpath` does literally exactly what the question wants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)