# Find a file base on knowing latter part of a path

Tags: python

I’m doing a coding project and wanted to ask something that would make my life so much easier.

Is there a syntax I can use to tell python to find the full file path if I know the latter half of it? For example if the full address is `C:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g.file`, but I know that I’m looking for `\d\e\f\g.file`, is there something I can do to find at least 1 path on my computer that would have that latter part of a file path. Sorry if this is badly worded, first time asking a question on here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Comment: Actually, this smells like a duplicate question to me. I noticed after answering, besides my answer might not apply across OS.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to provide an example of what you've tried. 
However, this seems straightforward to me.

You might be looking for absolute path?

```
import os

relative_path = '\d\e\f\g.file'
os.path.abspath(relative_path)
```