# Anyone have a "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" fix?

Tags: python, file, error-handling

Im attempting to open a file in a program but I got hit with this error: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

I saw that getting the absolute path instead of the relative path is a potential fix, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. If anyone has a way that I can get the absolute path of my file or has another way this can be fixed please let me know. Thank you in advance!

```
filename = "customer_records.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

a = []

for line in lines:
    a.append(line.split(","))
```

Comment: add the file with full path

Comment: How do I get the full path?

Comment: if you are working on linux/unix you can do `pwd`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This will print the current working directory.

```py
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

If the file is not in this folder then passing just the filename will not work.
You need to pass the full path (either relative or absolute).

For instance

```py
open("/home/my_user_name/some_folder/customer_records.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get the path of the file. Here is one way of getting the full path of your `customer_records.txt` file, assuming it's in the same directory as the running Python file:

```
import os

print ( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'customer_records.txt') )
```