# File Paths From Ch 10 Python Crash Course File Path Example

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to figure out how to use File Paths. This is the example that I am given but, it makes zero sense, I tried to copy the exact path that didn't work. I'm using Pycharm.

What I  tested

```
file_path = 'D:\PycharmProjects\Standard_Library\pi_digits.txt'
with open(file_path) as file_object:
```

Book Example Below

```
file_path = '/home/ehmatthes/other_files/text_files/filename.txt'
with open(file_path) as file_object:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Comment: @Pablo Welcome to StackOverflow! I will suggest to start with something simple like [1] Try to read 'D:\pi_digits.txt' (just place this file under D: volume). [2] Then, create a folder, say 'Test1' and cut/copy-paste the file there, then you can read it using 'D:\Test1\pi_digits.txt'.

Answer (score 1):

The author uses the Unix system and you are using the windows system and the only difference between the two examples is the file-separator.

In Python, you can declare separators either with hard-coded (For Unix: `/`, for windows: `\`)

But you can use `os.path` to remove the confusion of the os separator. Just place the text file in your current directory and you can use it in the example like below:

```
import os.path

text_file = 'pi_digits.txt'

file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), text_file)
print(file_path)
```

Out:

```
/Users/PycharmProjects/StackOverFlow-pip/pi_digits.txt
```

Since I'm also using a Unix system my example is similar to the book example. But If you try it in your pc you will see similar to the below:

```
'D:\PycharmProjects\Standard_Library\pi_digits.txt'
```

Then you can open the text file and read it using `with open(file_path) as file_object:`