# How can I find full path for a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have this path
`D:\something\something1\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2`.

So, I know that `\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2` is a permanent path, but the beginning is different, like I know that `D:\something\something1\` may be different for someone else. How can I find the `D:\something\something1\` knowing only `\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python

Comment: Have you tried os.path.abspath?

Comment: I tried any absolute path method, But I get something random honestly
Like I get everytime something that start from DISK C, and no files, nor path on that path it gives me. Even with hidden files on, no path

Comment: Ok guys, I have a question
Can you delete a folder, knowing only half of the full path?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import os

filestr = '\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2'
fullstr = os.path.abspath(filestr)

print(fullstr)
>>> 'D:\something\something1\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2'

print(fullstr[:len(filestr)])
>>> 'D:\something\something1'
```

Comment: I try, but gives me
C:\something\something1\from_here_I_now\stuff\stuff2
What I mean is that it gives a not real path
I have nothing on C related to it

Comment: You can try switching disks with `os.chdir('D:')`. To delete your folder you can try `os.rmdir('path')` for empty folders and `shutil.rmtree('path')` for non-empty folders. See a more detailed example [here](https://linuxize.com/post/python-delete-files-and-directories/)