# How to get the path of a file that i created python 3.10 win10

Tags: python

I want to print out the path of a file I created with open() in python 3.10.

The code I wrote to create the file:

```
file = open('genericName.name', 'wb')
file.write('some text')
file.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified files are created in the current working directory, you can find this value thanks to the `os` module:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```