# How to get the complete path of directory in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have directory `'/batchjobs/files/'`. I want to know the complete path of it.

Comment: I think this is what you are after: [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python). Short answer: `os.path.abspath('/batchjobs/files/')`

Comment: @JNevill I am looking for directory complete path, not a file's.

Comment: If you check on that duplicate link you will find lots of options, which is why I linked it. Perhaps the very top answer that is showing: `os.path.join( os.getcwd(), 'batchjobs/files/' )` would do the trick? There's likely lots of ways to solve this and most of them are listed out as optional answers there.

Comment: `/batchjobs/files` _is already_ an absolute path -- `/` is the root directory. It would be a relative path if it was `./batchjobs/files` or `batchjobs/files`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pathlib library.

```
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path('/batchjobs/files/').absolute())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dennis, but it returns /batchjobs only.
I need to get the complete path of /batchjobs/files/. which will be something like /A/B/C/batchjobs/files/

Comment: actually i think the parent. part was unnecessary, just made an edit to my answer, try this one instead pls