# I can't get the 3 files to be created on Windows

Tags: python, windows, file, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm on Windows and I can't get the 3 files to be created in the files folder. I went through the lecture im taking twice, and the previous lecture as well, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

This is my code now:

```
contents = ["All carrots are to be sliced longitudinally.", "The carrots were perfectly sliced.", "The carrots were reportedly sliced."]
 
filenames = ["doc.txt", "report.txt", "presentation.txt"]
 
for content, filename in zip(contents, filenames):
    file = open(f"../files/{filename}", 'w')
    file.write(content)
```

No matter what I try I keep getting the same error:

```
file = open(f"../files/{filename}", 'w')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../files/doc.txt'
```

I'm unsure what to do to fix this error, I would like some help with this issue.

I've tried the code written in the lecture:

```
for content, filename in zip(contents, filenames):
    file = open(f"../files/{filename}", 'w')
    file.write(content)
```

It didn't work.

I've also gone through the questions asked in the lecture and used 1 of the examples:

```
for content, filename in zip(contents, filenames):
    file_path = os.path.join("files", filename)
    file = open(file_path, 'w')
    file.write(content)
```

but that also didn't work.

Im expecting the code to create the 3 files `["doc.txt", "report.txt", "presentation.txt"]` and save each string in the files in order `["All carrots are to be sliced longitudinally.", "The carrots were perfectly sliced.", "The carrots were reportedly sliced."]`. For instance, `"All carrots are to be sliced longitudinally."` would be saved in `"doc.txt"`, and so on for the other strings.

Comment: The error refers to the path, not the file itself. Keep in mind that `../files` is relative to where the CWD of the interpreter is, so `../files` may refer to `myproject/files` instead of `myproject/src/files` as you may or may not expect.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950650

Answer (score 0):

Try running code in terminal.

If it works, then create a new configuration file to run files from PyCharm run button.

Otherwise check if you have permissions to write files in that directory (where you ran code)

Run with admin permissions (if you don't have permissions)